# SSD won't show up in RAID utility but shows on Windows

Tags: ssd, raid

I have two SSDs, installed on a ASUS z77v pro motherboard: A Samsung 840 and 850 EVO.

My Windows 10 (64-bit) installation is on the 840. It works. It runs. I’m on Windows right now using it. But when I go into my bios to set up the raid drives, only my 850 will show on the list of drives. It shows the 840 on my boot menu but not the raid utility.

Does it have to be a formatted blank drive? I don’t think thats the case considering it can see my 500GB and 1TB HDDs which arent blank.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual for that board](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8Z77-V_PRO/E7198_P8Z77-V_PRO.pdf) (section 2.2.8), not all the SATA ports on that motherboard are linked to the Intel Rapid Storage RAID controller.

Specifically, the SATA 6.0 Gb/s ports labelled "SATA6G_E1" and "SATA6G_E2", are not.

So if your drive is connected to one of those, that's why it's not showing in the setup of the RAID controller.

Comment: To add to that: Either connect both to the Intel chipsets SATA ports, then configure it from normal AHCI to 'fake RAID' and use Intels software RAID, **or** use software RAID from windows. I have no win10 here but in win 7 you could find that under disk management (Start, run, `diskmgmt.msc`).